# Shouldn't my while loop stop running after the fighter's health is false?

Tags: javascript, function, while-loop, boolean

The result is accurate I believe but the loop continues to run when it is false. I even reset the fighter's health to zero in order to force the loop to close but it continues to run until both are zero. Please if you have any recommendations I will go back and fix the code myself but I am very confused. Thanks

```
function Fighter(name, health, damagePerAttack) {
        this.name = name;
        this.health = health;
        this.damagePerAttack = damagePerAttack;
        this.toString = function() { return this.name; }
}




function declareWinner(fighter1, fighter2, firstAttacker) {
  var result,
      winner;

  if (fighter1.name == firstAttacker) {
    firstAttacker = fighter1;
    battlev1();
  } else if (fighter2.name == firstAttacker) {
    firstAttacker = fighter2;
    battlev2();
  } else {
    console.log(`${firstAttacker} isn't fighting right now!`)
    return
  }

  function resetHealth(p) {
    p.health = 0;
  }

  function resultsv1() {
    if (firstAttacker.health <= 0) {
        result = `${fighter2.name} attacks ${firstAttacker.name}; ${firstAttacker.name} now has ${firstAttacker.health} health and is dead. ${fighter2.name} wins`;
        winner = fighter2.name;
        console.log(winner);
        resetHealth(fighter2);
    } else if (fighter2.name <= 0) {
        result = `${firstAttacker.name} attacks ${fighter2.name}; ${fighter2.name} now has ${fighter2.health} health and is dead. ${firstAttacker.name} wins`;
        winner = firstAttacker.name;
        console.log(winner);
        resetHealth(firstAttacker);
    }
  }

  function resultsv2(){
    if (firstAttacker.health <= 0) {
        result = `${fighter1.name} attacks ${firstAttacker.name}; ${firstAttacker.name} now has ${firstAttacker.health} health and is dead. ${fighter1.name} wins`;
        winner = fighter1.name;
        console.log(winner);
        resetHealth(fighter1);
    } else if (fighter1.name <= 0) {
        fighter1.health = 0;
        result = `${firstAttacker.name} attacks ${fighter2.name}; ${fighter2.name} now has ${fighter2.health} health and is dead. ${firstAttacker.name} wins`;
        winner = firstAttacker.name
        console.log(winner);
        resetHealth(firstAttacker);
    }
  }

  function determineLifeStatusv1() {
    resultsv1();
  }

  function determineLifeStatusv2() {
    resultsv2();
  }

  function fightv1() {
    determineLifeStatusv1();
    fighter2.health -= firstAttacker.damagePerAttack;
    result = `${firstAttacker.name} attacks ${fighter2.name}; ${fighter2.name} now has ${fighter2.health} health.`;
    console.log(result);
    determineLifeStatusv1();
    firstAttacker.health -= fighter2.damagePerAttack;
    result = `${fighter2.name} attacks ${firstAttacker.name}; ${firstAttacker.name} now has ${firstAttacker.health} health.`;
    console.log(result);
    determineLifeStatusv1();
  }

  function fightv2() {
    determineLifeStatusv2()
    fighter1.health -= firstAttacker.damagePerAttack;
    result = `${firstAttacker.name} attacks ${fighter1.name}; ${fighter1.name} now has ${fighter1.health} health.`;
    console.log(result);
    determineLifeStatusv2()
    firstAttacker.health -= fighter1.damagePerAttack;
    result = `${fighter1.name} attacks ${firstAttacker.name}; ${firstAttacker.name} now has ${firstAttacker.health} health.`;
    console.log(result);
    determineLifeStatusv2()
  }

  function battlev1() {
    while (firstAttacker.health > 0 && fighter2.health > 0) {
      fightv1();
    }
  }

  function battlev2() {
    while (fighter1.health > 0 && firstAttacker.health > 0) {
      firstAttacker.health = 0;
      fightv2();
    }
  }

}

declareWinner(new Fighter("Lew", 10, 2), new Fighter("Harry", 5, 4), "Harry");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in your function `fightv2`. You have to finish function if first fighter is dead.

```
function fightv2() {
  determineLifeStatusv2()
  fighter1.health -= firstAttacker.damagePerAttack;
  result = `${firstAttacker.name} attacks ${fighter1.name}; ${fighter1.name} now has ${fighter1.health} health.`;
  console.log(result);

  // you have to quit function if fighter1 is dead, like so
  if(fighter1.health <= 0) return;

  determineLifeStatusv2()
  firstAttacker.health -= fighter1.damagePerAttack;
  result = `${fighter1.name} attacks ${firstAttacker.name}; ${firstAttacker.name} now has ${firstAttacker.health} health.`;
  console.log(result);
  determineLifeStatusv2()
}
```